# RegEx Vin Validation Pre 1981

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a RegEx Vin Validation for Vehicles previous of 1981.

This is what I have come up with for vehicles post 1980:

```
^[A-Z\d]{8}[\dX][A-Z\d]{2}\d{6}$
```

Has anyone ever created a RegEx Vin Validation pre 1981? This is more difficult than I thought.

http://www.crankshaftcoalition.com/wiki/VIN_decoding

Comment: Someone must have created something to catch VIN numbers prior to 1981 ... Or have done something tying it with the year saying if it is prior to 1981 Skip RegEx or something I would think.. How does the DMV recognize a valid verse not valid VIN then?

Answer (score 1):

A better post 1980 Vin Validation would be `^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$` since they did not use I O or Q.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number.  I don't think you would be able to create a regex for pre 1980 because every company did something different...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `^((?!.{9}[su])[a-z0-9-[io]]{11}\d{6}|[a-hj-z0-9]{6,11}\d{5})$`